# Can I throw exception based on method signature in ASM?

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm

I am fiddling with [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org) framework for sometimes. I just want to catch exceptions.

So far , I am able to insert `try-catch` blocks in bytecode and catch the exception.

This is what I am doing now.

```
public void visitMaxs(int maxStack, int maxLocals)
    {
        // visit try block end label
        this.visitLabel(lblTryBlockEnd);
        // visit normal execution exit block
        //this.visitJumpInsn(Opcodes.GOTO, exitBlock);

        // visit catch exception block
        this.visitLabel(lblCatchExceptionBlockStart);
        // store the exception
        this.visitVarInsn(Opcodes.ASTORE, 1);
        super.visitTypeInsn(Opcodes.NEW, "java/lang/Exception");
        super.visitInsn(Opcodes.DUP);

        // load the exception
        this.visitVarInsn(Opcodes.ALOAD, 1);
        // Initializing the exception object with the throwable cause
        super.visitMethodInsn(Opcodes.INVOKESPECIAL, "java/lang/Exception", "<init>", "(Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V");

        // calling jensor method to write
        super.visitMethodInsn(Opcodes.INVOKESTATIC, 
                "test/ExceptionHandleTest", 
                "exceptionHandler", 
        "(Ljava/lang/Exception;)V");
                // call printStackTrace()
       this.visitInsn(Opcodes.ATHROW);



        // exit from this dynamic block
        this.visitLabel(exitBlock);

        super.visitMaxs(maxStack+2, maxLocals);

    }
`
```

Now , I do not want to throw every caught exception ( as I am doing `athrow` every time now ) , instead I want to throw only if it matches with `exception` parameter of method signature of `MethodVisitor`.

I tried to do so , but got `Falling off the end of the code` class verify error.

Is it possible to do using ASM ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this, I suggest your write what you want in Java and ASMifier the byte code to see how it is structured.

There is an ASM plugin for IDEs which make this easier.

Comment: Yes, ASMifier is great

Answer (score 0):

Your code fragment gives too little information about what you really do. You say that you want to (re)throw the exception under a certain condition only but you don’t say what you want to do otherwise. That perfectly matches the verifier error: if you skip the throw instruction under certain conditions and have not provided an alternative end of the method your code falls off the end of the method. You have to provide code for that case, e.g. a controlled return. The alternative is not to catch exceptions that don’t meet your criteria but that would end up the same behavior as re-throwing all exceptions.